# Error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token|

Tags: c++, binary-tree, codeblocks

I am trying to implement a Binary Search Tree. The code isn't complete, but I built it anyways to see what possible errors I would get.
Here is the code for it:

*BST.h*

```
class BST {

    public:
    struct node
    {
        //All nodes must be able to point to left and right
        int key;  //All nodes can hold a key value
        node* left; //All nodes have a left pointer
        node* right;//All nodes have a right pointer
    };

    node* root; //References the very top of the tree

    public:
        BST(); //Constructor that initializes each time instance is called
        node* CreateLeaf(int key);

};
```

*BST.cpp*

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

#include "BST.h"
using namespace std;

BST::BST()
{
    root = NULL;
}

node* BST::CreateLeaf(int key) //Causing errors
{
    node* n = new node;
    n->key = key;
    n->left = NULL;
    n->right = NULL;
    return n;
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "BST.cpp"


using namespace std;

int main()
{

return 0;
}
```

This gives the error:
Error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token

In the BST.cpp file, if I declare the CreateLeaf() function as:

```
typedef node* BST::CreateLeaf(int key)
```

the error changes to:
Error: expected initializer before '*' token

Now, with common sense, since I am declaring the CreateLeaf function outside the class, I do this:

```
BST::node* BST::CreateLeaf(int key)
```

Now the error becomes:
Error: In function BST: multiple definition of `BST::BST()'

I am using the CodeBlocks IDE on Windows 10.

**EDIT:**
I removed the .cpp file and declared all functions inside the header file (and included header file in the main function). Now it is compiling. But it would be great if someone could let me know why the error was occurring in the first place.

Comment: What's the error location?

Comment: You don't include .cpp files; that's not how it's supposed to work.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FPjmO3-6IY&list=PLTxllHdfUq4d-DE16EDkpeb8Z68DU7Z_Q&index=5
I am using this video as the reference. It works for him, why not for me?

Comment: "*Why not "BST.h" instead of including "BST.cpp". Many people told me including your source files is considered as a bad practice.*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the declaration

```
node* BST::CreateLeaf(int key)
```

… the name `node` is not known to the compiler, because it's defined within the `BST` class and it's here used outside of that class.

One simple fix is to use the newer trailing return type syntax:

```
auto BST::CreateLeaf(int key)
    -> node*
```

Here the compiler knows that the declaration belongs to the `BST` class, at the point where it encounters `node`.

Alternatively you can qualify the name,

```
BST::node* BST::CreateLeaf(int key)
```

… but that can get ugly fast, especially with template code.

---

In other news, the

```
#include "BST.cpp"
```

… in file `main.cpp` is ungood practice. One practical reason is that in an IDE project this may cause that code to be compiled twice: one compilation of `BST.cpp`, and one compilation of that same code as included in `main.cpp`.

Instead just compile `BST.cpp` separately.

Or, design it as a header file module (mainly this involves declaring functions as `inline`).

Comment: Using auto generates another error. It says it expects an initializer before the '*' token.

Comment: I removed the BST.cpp file. I declared all class functions inside the class in the BST.h file. Now it is compiling successfully...

Comment: Be sure to mark all function implementations that you move to header file, as `inline` (otherwise you can get linker error when the header is used in two or more translation units). Regarding the "auto generates another error", I could not reproduce that. Possibly a typo.

Comment: Doesn't using #import instead of #include solve the issue of header files getting included in multiple locations? It checks first if it is present and if not then it includes.

Comment: @SaunvedMutalik: `#import` can be [(1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) a Microsoft language extension for dealing with COM modules, or (2) if I remember correctly a proposed C++ module syntax, not yet standardized, but experimentally implemented by Visual C++. It may be that in the sense of (2) it will work roughly like you say. But I haven't used it so I don't know, sorry.

Comment: Oh, regarding (2), for C++17 modules it's just `import`, not `#import` (again, sorry, I haven't used this future functionality). More info [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/03/c-modules-in-vs-2015-update-1/), including links to discussion and proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Outside the class declaration you need to prefix the scope to `node`:

```
   BST::node* BST::CreateLeaf(int key) { 
// ^^^^^ ...
   }
```

Also you shouldn't include `.cpp` files. Include the header, and compile and link the `.cpp` files separately.

Comment: Check out my last few lines of the question. Doing this generates the error:
error:multiple definition of `BST::BST()'|

Comment: It's certainly one (awkward) solution, but there's no “**need**” to do it that way.

Comment: @SaunvedMutalik You're still not telling us the error location.

Comment: What do you mean by error location? The error occurs at the declaration of CreateLeaf() in the BST.cpp file.